# Função Getdata VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

Estou a tentar criar uma função para actualizar a Datagridview.
Adicionei os seguinte código mas da um erro "Não É possível limpar a lista"

Codigo:

```
    Private Sub GetData()
    Try
        con = New SqlConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT nome, matricula, marca, [Licenca-emissao], [licenca-expira] from Clientes order by Nome", con)
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        dgw.Rows.Clear()
        While (rdr.Read() = True)
            dgw.Rows.Add(rdr(0), rdr(1))
        End While
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: vc está setando o DataSource do seu dgw em algum lugar antes?

Comment: @BrunoPiovan nao percebi o "SETANDO"

Comment: vc está atribuindo a propriedade DataSource anteriormente em algum outro lugar?

Comment: @BrunoPiovan Sim, em varias Forms

Comment: é por isso então, vc não pode limpar as rows pois existe um datasource atribuido, vc tem que limpar as "rows" do seu datasource. Vou responder com uma recomendação.

Comment: @BrunoPiovan sou um desenvolvedor amador ainda, podia facilitar um pouco. E percebo mais programação em inglês

Comment: ok! check these out, might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184402/how-can-i-clear-rows-in-datagridview-with-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151641/filling-a-datagridview-from-sqlreader

Comment: Obrigado, mas esta em C#, nunca mexi em C# @BrunoPiovan

Comment: Tentei usar a funcao
dataTable.Clear
dataGridView.Refresh


Mais não deu certo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta isso:

```
Private Sub GetData()
    Try
        con = New SqlConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT nome, matricula, marca, [Licenca-emissao], [licenca-expira] from Clientes order by Nome", con)
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        Dim dt = New DataTable()
        dt.Load(rdr)
        dgw.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        dgw.DataSource = dt
        dgw.Refresh()

        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Como eu disse nos comentário, você não pode limpar as linhas pois você mesmo disse que está atribuindo um DataSource anteriormente, então você precisa mexer nele, e não nas linhas do seu DataGridView.

Comment: Agradecido, vou verificar isso, depois digo algo :)

Comment: Muito agradecido @BrunoPiovan funcionou :) Gastei noites e noites a tentar resolver isso...

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado! Se puder aceite esta resposta como a correta então. =)